# Google Apps Scripts does not save logs

Tags: google-apps-script, logging, google-cloud-platform

I created a script a few years ago and recently revisited it, to try and get the logging working. I added various `console.info` functions and tested it. It worked fine and I was able to see all the logs during execution.

[image: Logs appear during execution]

However, the logs never appear in the Google Apps Script dashboard.

[image: Lack of logs on the Google Apps Script dashboard]

At the moment this screenshot was taken, more than 3 hours had passed since the execution.

When consulting the GCP console (by clicking **View in Cloud Logging**), even when setting a generic query, no logs are found.

[image: GCP console doesn't show any logs]

I have been reading the documentation and trying to understand what the problem may be. From what I understand, some logging features only work for standard GCP projects, mainly accessing info in the GCP console. My script does not belong to a standard GCP project, it belongs to a default GCP project (they're different things from what I understood).

[image: The GCP project associated with my script is a Default GCP project]

But according to the documentation, [a default GCP project allows for logs to be accessed through the Apps Script dashboard](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#default_cloud_platform_projects). So the logs should be visible in the executions. I'm probably missing something, but I'm having a hard time figuring out what. Any suggestions would be welcome.

**Minimal Reproducible Example**

Here is a code example, whose logs appear on execution but not after.

```
function main() {
  const xml = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.imdb.com/calendar/?region=pt').getContentText();
  const xmlSliced = xml.slice(xml.search('<div id="main">'), xml.search('<div id="sidebar">') - 1);
  const document = XmlService.parse(xmlSliced);

  const dates = document.getRootElement().getChildren('h4');

  console.info(`Parsed ${dates.length} release dates`);
}
```

[image: Minimal Reproducible Example]

Comment: If this is a published web app, I believe this is a known issue.

Comment: @TheMaster not a web app, just a scheduled script that adds events to my calendar

Comment: Try using Logger.log()

Comment: What do you see when you click on "View in cloud"?

Comment: @Cooper I had Logger.log() before the recent changes, no logs were saved either

Comment: @Kos it open the GCP console and it doesn't show any logs. I've added a screenshot to the post

Comment: @FilipeBarbosa do you have "Log uncaught exceptions to Cloud logs" enabled in project settings?

Comment: @Kos yes, I have "Log uncaught exceptions to Cloud logs" enabled

Comment: Would it be possible for you to share a minimal, reproducible example for us to further check the issue? [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @RonM just added it to the post

Comment: Is this a standalone script? So basically, the logs is visible if you manually run the script in the editor, But when the function was time-triggered the logs is not visible in the execution tab?

Comment: @RonM it is a standalone script. The logs are visible when I manually run the script because I can see the execution tab, but they don't appear anywhere else. When the script is time-triggered, as you said, I can't see the logs anywhere.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. Have you tried copying your legacy code and create a new standalone script? Is this issue exist in your other scripts? If creating a new script doesn't fix your issue, I suggest that you file an issue in  https://issuetracker.google.com/

Comment: @RonM it actually worked strangely enough. Don't know why it doesn't in the original project. I'm going to leave the question unsolved to see if a solution surfaces, someone may need it in the future. Thanks.